# Reading a blob field from database using IDataRecord

Tags: .net, ado.net, datareader

I need to populate a byte array from a database field using an IDataRecord and i needed help on how to get this done.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public byte[] ImageData { get; set;}
}
```

// Data Layer

```
public MyClass Populate(IDataRecord dr)
{
   var myClass = new MyClass();
   myClass.Name = myDataRecord.GetString(myDataRecord.GetOrdinal("NAME"));
   myClass.ImageData = // Need info on how to load this

}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply cast by using [GetValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getvalue.aspx) method:

```
public MyClass Populate(IDataRecord dr)
{
   var myClass = new MyClass();

   int ordinal1 = myDataRecord.GetOrdinal("NAME");
   int ordinal2 = myDataRecord.GetOrdinal("IMAGEDATA");

   myClass.Name = myDataRecord.GetString(ordinal1);
   myClass.ImageData = (byte[])myDataRecord.GetValue(ordinal2);
}
```

**EDIT:** The GetOrdinal() is necessary for reading the ordinal of a field by name.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason that you can't use [`IDataRecord.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.getbytes.aspx) as in

```
int imageDataOrdinal = myDataRecord.GetOrdinal("ImageData");
long bytesRead = myDataRecord.GetBytes(
                     imageDataOrdinal,
                     0,
                     myClass.ImageData,
                     0
                     length
                 );
```

Comment: Please explain how to set the value of the length parameter

Comment: @ Carl Onager:  `myDataRecord.GetBytes(imageDataOrdinal, 0, null, 0, 0)`. This is mentioned in the remarks section of the documentation page ('If you pass a buffer that is null, GetBytes returns the length of the row in bytes.'). The 'row' thing is misleading, of course. It should probably read 'blob' or something like that.